# Pet Store Problem?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Hi I answered the problems just wanted to verify if my approach was correct. Any suggestions appreciated.

**Question**: A pet store has 6 puppies, 9 kittens, 4 lizards, and 5 snakes.

**a.** If you select a pet from the store randomly, what is the probability that it is a snake?

**Answer:** 5/24

**b.** If you select two pets from the store randomly, what is the probability that they are both the same
species?

**Answer:**$\dfrac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{9}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{24}{2}}$

**c.** If you select five pets from the store randomly, what is the probability that at least one of the pets is
a puppy?

**Answer:** $1 - \dfrac{\binom{18}{5}}{\binom{24}{5}}$

Comment: Who selects their pet randomly?

Comment: To produce $\binom{n}{k}$, type \binom{n}{k} between dollar signs.  To produce $\frac{a}{b}$, type \frac{a}{b} between dollar signs.  Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b)
once you have chosen 2 out of 6 puppies,you are not going to choose 2 out of 9 kittens,2 out of 4 lizards and 2 out of 5 snakes. It is going to be 2 of any one species. So the correct answer must be:

$$\frac{\binom{6}{2} + \binom{9}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{5}{2}}{\binom{24}{2}}$$

Comment: To type $\binom{n}{k}$, type \binom{n}{k} between dollar signs.  To type $\frac{a}{b}$, type \frac{a}{b} between dollar signs.  Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset  mathematics on this site.